# Installing Ubuntu on external drive for someone else, from inside Ubuntu

Tags: boot, system-installation, external-hdd

This may sound a stupid question, but this is something I'm not finding obvious documentation for.

I'm running Ubuntu on my laptop. Someone has given me an old HD, currently in an external case, and I want to install Ubuntu on it, so that she can then take the HD, remove it from the case, and install it as the main drive in her old computer, ready to boot into Ubuntu.

I don't want to mess with the installation on my own machine. I'm not in Windows, so I suppose I don't need to make another pendrive with Ubuntu. I don't just want to put an "image" on the external drive because I'm not trying to give her an installer. I'm trying to give her an HD with Ubuntu already installed.

So what steps do I actually need to take to do this?

Comment: You say old computer, but Microsoft has required vendors to install in UEFI/gpt mode since release of Windows 8 in 2012. If older than that it then would be BIOS/MBR. Install directions are a bit different if UEFI or BIOS. You do need to partition in advance and if BIOS can install grub boot loader to MBR. But if UEFI, Ubuntu's Ubiquity will only install boot loader to internal drive, overwriting your boot. You can reconfigure & manually reinstall grub to fix. Also see work around during install in #23 & 26
https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/ubiquity/+bug/1396379

Answer (score 1):

You are creating several unnecessary problems with this approach.

- The Ubuntu Installer is not included in the installed system. It remains on the installation media.
- She cannot test her hardware in the Live environment (Example: Do we know if her WiFi will work?)
- You're not installing a bootloader, so she may not be able to boot the installation.
- Her machine might have a different architecture than yours.

There is no EASY way to install Ubuntu without using an installer.

There are many *advanced ways* to install Ubuntu without using an installer. Most bare-metal installs are variations on [the debootstap chroot method](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/DebootstrapChroot). Container and VM installs (non-bare-metal) generally involve booting a [cloud-image](https://cloud-images.ubuntu.com/) or manually creating an [ubuntu-base](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Base) install, but those generally don't work on bare metal. Feel free to experiment with advanced methods...on a system without any data that you might lose!

**Advice for new users**: It's not difficult re-purpose a USB stick for a few minutes to run the Ubuntu Installer. It's Live environment for testing hardware and it's sensible defaults are a safe, easy, reliable way to install Ubuntu.

Comment: Well the issue is I'm not going to see her. (Because of COVID lockdown etc.) So can't be there to help with the install. I'm just sending her the disk. The idea was to give her something as easy as possible. But I take your point.